# Use name of Docker (Flask) service inside package.json of React app

Tags: reactjs, docker

I'm trying to have my React front end application interact with a Flask API, both Dockerized and built together with `docker-compose`. Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    server:
        build: ./server
        ports:
            - "80:5000"
        volumes:
            - ./server:/app
        environment:
            FLASK_ENV: development
        env_file: 
            - ./.env
    web:
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/user/src/app
        depends_on: 
            - server
```

The `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "housing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  
  ...

  "proxy":"http://server:80"
}
```

And then in `App.js` file trying to call the API with:

```
callAPI( some_arg ) {
        var h = new Headers();
        h.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        h.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        var raw = JSON.stringify({"some_arg":some_arg});

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: h,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };

        const url = '/api/some_service'

        fetch(url, requestOptions).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({some_component_data: data});
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately doing this results in an error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/some_service from localhost:3000 to http://server:80.
```

It works fine if I replace `server` with `0.0.0.0` but I'd quite like to use the actual container name in `package.json`. How can I do this?

Comment: If the process inside the `server` container is listening on port 5000, that needs to be the port number in the `"proxy"` setting.  Connections between containers don't use (or need) `ports:`.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Looks like I misunderstood how connections worked between containers.

Answer (score 1):

My use case is a little different (django + redis), but I would try some combination of these 2 things:

- Remove the http:// and just use server:80
- Specify container_name in your docker-compose file. I don't know if this is actually necessary or if it uses the service name to connect, but worth a shot if the first thing doesn't work alone.

For my use case, the connection string is just `redis://redis` and the docker-compose section for that service looks like this:

```
redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    command: redis-server --requirepass <password>
    volumes:
        - redis_data:/data
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
```

Comment: `container_name:` is unnecessary here.